# In Google Sheets can you count the number of rows with a certain criteria like WEEKNUM() and YEAR()?

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, countif

I have a column of dates:

```
2/7/2020 3:51:37
2/7/2020 1:11:16
2/6/2020 23:41:58
2/6/2020 23:33:49
2/6/2020 23:31:47
3/6/2020 23:28:12
2/6/2020 23:26:39
2/4/2020 23:22:43
2/6/2020 23:22:22
2/3/2021 23:05:59
2/6/2021 23:02:09
1/2/2021 22:59:58
1/5/2021 22:56:24
2/3/2022 22:27:43
2/6/2022 21:58:04
2/6/2022 21:49:01
```

And I would like to use `COUNTIFS` to count the number of rows where the date is a certain week of the year `X` and and certain year `Y`. Without having to compute another column first?

EDIT:

I tried some like:

`=COUNTIFS(A:A, WEEKNUM(A:A) = 10, A:A, YEAR(A:A) = 2020)` but that doesn't really make sense a I'm passing a range to `WEEKNUM` and `YEAR`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your criteria_range and criterion are not match, please change your formula like this:

=arrayformula(countifs(weeknum(F:F),10,year(F:F),2020))

or

=arrayformula(COUNTIF((WEEKNUM(F:F) = 10)* (YEAR(F:F) = 2020),1))

[image]

Answer (score 0):

non of your dates does what you want so the result is 0

formula is:

```
=SUM(INDEX(COUNTIFS(WEEKNUM(A:A), 10, YEAR(A:A), 2020)))
```

[image: 0]

---

[image: 0]